# Python Multiple Keys and Transform to Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, pandas-groupby, data-wrangling

I am importing a txt file in Python 2.6.6, and need to do some data wrangling. I am new to Python and am struggling to google every step to complete the task. Could you help or suggest?

Here is my input *myData.txt* shown below. The header is not in the data, but I put it here for easier reading.

```
key1|key2|group|v1|v2|v3|v4
1|A|-1|10|100|1|2
1|A|2|20|35|2|3
1|B|1|15|5|3|5
2|B|5|23|25|4|2
2|B|2|33|20|22|98    
2|D|4|23|21|20|32
...
```

Here is my desired output in a panda dataframe shown below. Basically, I want to merge key1 and key2 and form a combo key, and put group, v1, and v2 into a dictionary with group as the key, and v1 v2 as the values in a list (v1 being the first element, and v2 being the second element). I don't need v3 or v4 in the output.

```
     comboKey1  new_v1
     1_A        {"-1":[10,100], "2":[20,35]}
     1_B        {"1":[15,5]}
     2_B        {"2":[33,20], "5":[23,25]}
     2_D        {"4":[23,21]}
```

Here is what I have now.  Could someone kindly advise?

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('myData.txt', header=None, sep='|')
df1.columns = ('key1','key2','group','v1','v2')
df1['comboKey1'] = df1['key1'].map(str)+"_"+df1['key2']
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using Python 2? Can you be more specific about which part you're struggling with?

Comment: @AMC Because I don't have authorization to upgrade it to a newer version. I was struggling with the next step, which is to organize the data and make it the output I want.

Comment: If you want to learn Python in the future, I strongly recommended you switch to Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 import pandas as pd

 # Reading file, 'r' -> read
 file = open('data.txt', 'r')
 lines = file.readlines()

 # Fict where info will be stored
 main_dict = {}

 for line in lines:
     # Getting the list of values in the line
     # values -> [key1, key2, group, v1, v2, v3, v4]
     # indexs ->   0     1      2     3   4   5   6
     values = line.split('|')

     #creating combo_key
     combo_key = str(values[0])+"_"+str(values[1])

     #tests if key already exists
     #if not, creats a new dict into it
     if combo_key not in main_dict.keys():
         main_dict[combo_key] = {}   #adding new dict to dict key

     main_dict[combo_key][str(values[2])] = [values[3], values[4]]

 data = []
 for key in main_dict.keys():
     data.append([key, str(main_dict[key])])

 df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ComboKey1', "new_v1"])

 print(df)
```

Just sort the dict, then (:

Comment: @Fernando Costa Do you know how to make the output a table? I tried to use `pd.DataFrame(main_dict)`, but it gives me a different format from my desired output shown in my original post.

Comment: .@Dautomne_  It doesn't give me a table as shown in the original post. It gives me lines. It is pretty close, but different.

Comment: Hello, @Counter10000. I hope it can help you.
You can bring it to the table format doing:
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(main_dict, orient="index)
print df

It's the table representation of a Dict of Dict.

Comment: Hello, @Dautomne_ I tried your suggestion. It is transposing the table. Is there a way we can put it as shown in my original table? Basically, I only need 2 columns. First the combo key, second the dictionary with group being key, v1, and v2 being values.

Comment: @Counter10000 Juts edited my code. Please, take a look if it helps you and, then, drop me a message xD

Comment: Hi @Dautomen_ Perfect. Could you edit your first line in your answer, where you initially mentioned no library is needed.

Comment: Hello, @Counter10000 (: I'm glad it solved your problem. Just edited my answer. Best regards XD

Answer (score 0):

If just achieve the desired expected output, then the following code can apply too.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

YOUR_TXT_DATA = """\
1|A|-1|10|100|1|2
1|A|2|20|35|2|3
1|B|1|15|5|3|5
2|B|5|23|25|4|2
2|B|2|33|20|22|98    
2|D|4|23|21|20|32
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(YOUR_TXT_DATA), header=None,
                 usecols=[_ for _ in range(0, 5)],
                 names=['key1', 'key2', 'group', 'v1', 'v2'],
                 sep='|')
result_dict = dict(comboKey1=[], new_v1=[])
for key1, key2, group, v1, v2 in df.values:
    key = str(key1) + '_' + str(key2)
    if key not in result_dict['comboKey1']:
        result_dict['comboKey1'].append(key)
        result_dict['new_v1'].append({str(group): [v1, v2]})
    else:
        index = result_dict['comboKey1'].index(key)
        result_dict['new_v1'][index].update({str(group): [v1, v2]})

result_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result_dict)
print(result_df)
```

output

```
  comboKey1                            new_v1
0       1_A  {'-1': [10, 100], '2': [20, 35]}
1       1_B                    {'1': [15, 5]}
2       2_B    {'5': [23, 25], '2': [33, 20]}
3       2_D                   {'4': [23, 21]}
```

---

## About Test Data

I think there is some special cases that you may need to consider, assuming the data is as follows.

```
key1|key2|group|v1|v2|v3|v4
1|A|-1|10|100|1|2
1|A|-1|10|100|1|2
1|A|-1|20|35|2|3
```

what is your expected output? (case 1 ~ 3)

- case 1: be subject to last. `1_A  {'-1': [20, 35]}`  (solution: dict)
- case 2: keep all but not duplicate: `{('-1', (10, 100)), ('-1', (20, 35))}`  (solution: set)
- case 3: keep all `1_A  [('-1', (10, 100)), ('-1', (10, 100)), ('-1', (20, 35))]`  (solution: list)

code:

```
from unittest import TestCase
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

OTHER_TXT_DATA = """\
1|A|-1|10|100|1|2
1|A|-1|10|100|1|2
1|A|-1|20|35|2|3
"""

class MyTests(TestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **options):
        super().__init__(*args, **options)
        self.df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(OTHER_TXT_DATA), header=None,
                              usecols=[_ for _ in range(0, 5)],
                              names=['key1', 'key2', 'group', 'v1', 'v2'],
                              sep='|')

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        # init on every test case.
        self.result_dict = dict(comboKey1=[], new_v1=[])

    def solution_base(self, new_v1_fun, update_v1_fun) -> pd.DataFrame:

        result_dict = self.result_dict

        for key1, key2, group, v1, v2 in self.df.values:
            key = str(key1) + '_' + str(key2)
            if key not in result_dict['comboKey1']:
                result_dict['comboKey1'].append(key)
                new_v1_fun(group, v1, v2)  # result_dict['new_v1'].append({str(group): [v1, v2]})
            else:
                index = result_dict['comboKey1'].index(key)
                update_v1_fun(index, group, v1, v2)  # result_dict['new_v1'][index].update({str(group): [v1, v2]})

        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result_dict)
        print(df)
        return df

    def test_case_1_dict(self):
        df = self.solution_base(new_v1_fun=lambda group, v1, v2: self.result_dict['new_v1'].append({str(group): [v1, v2]}),
                                update_v1_fun=lambda index, group, v1, v2: self.result_dict['new_v1'][index].update({str(group): [v1, v2]}))
        self.assertTrue(df.equals(pd.DataFrame(
            columns=['comboKey1', 'new_v1'],
            data=[
                ['1_A', {'-1': [20, 35]}],
            ]
        )))

    def test_case_2_set(self):
        df = self.solution_base(new_v1_fun=lambda group, v1, v2: self.result_dict['new_v1'].append({(str(group), (v1, v2))}),
                                update_v1_fun=lambda index, group, v1, v2: self.result_dict['new_v1'][index].add((str(group), (v1, v2))))
        self.assertTrue(df.equals(pd.DataFrame(
            columns=['comboKey1', 'new_v1'],
            data=[
                ['1_A', {('-1', (20, 35)), ('-1', (10, 100))}],
            ]
        )))

    def test_case_3_list(self):
        df = self.solution_base(new_v1_fun=lambda group, v1, v2: self.result_dict['new_v1'].append([(str(group), (v1, v2))]),
                                update_v1_fun=lambda index, group, v1, v2: self.result_dict['new_v1'][index].append((str(group), (v1, v2))))
        self.assertTrue(df.equals(pd.DataFrame(
            columns=['comboKey1', 'new_v1'],
            data=[
                ['1_A', [('-1', (10, 100)), ('-1', (10, 100)), ('-1', (20, 35))]],
            ]
        )))
```

**note:** annotation (see [PEP484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)) is not supported Python 2.